# Lowest energy wireless protocol for specific wireless sensor node

Tags: wireless, low-power

There are so many options for low-power wireless communication these days. BLE is everywhere, and many other manufacturers try to push their protocols as well. LoRa, Dust, Zigbee, Thread, Sigfox, etc., the list is long. What I think is lacking is a good way to compare the total energy consumption. Data rate and transmit power are easy, but there are so many other variables that make it difficult to compare.

What is interesting is the lowest possible energy consumption for a transmission period, and thereby the longest possible lifespan, but obviously also for the sensor node to function in the environment it is designed for.

This question would be much too broad without some constraints, so these are listed below.

Q: Which is the most low energy wireless protocol?

**Constraints:**

- Industrial enviroment (WiFi present, but not crowded 2.4 GHz like
  residential areas)
- Data packages of 10 kB (kilobytes)
- Range up to 150 m inside steel structure with some steel obstacles
- Transmission period 1/week
- Network of potentially 1000 nodes
- Highly predictable lifespan if supplied from primary battery
- It is allowed for a power manager to disable the voltage supply to the wireless subsystem, though some protocols are designed to be always powered and have a low power keep-alive communication going (Dust comes to mind)

Comment: This is **not** a shopping question. OP is asking for a protocol comparison. Relevant: http://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2011/aug/comparing-low-power-wireless-technologies

Comment: Do you need mesh routing? Or is it enough that each battery-powered device sends data directly to a master node?

Comment: @filo It depends. For a long range protocol without problems functioning in a steel structure, mesh is not required. For other cases it might be required. I think it would not be an advantage, because it would load some nodes more than others and likely make lifespan difficult to predict.

Comment: I don't think this can be answered at all. You cannot compare the power consumption of protocols, only of their implementations. And comparing implementations kind of does turn it into a shopping question.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Well, you should read the linked article I posted above. It doesn't mention a single specific chip/module, though it actually compares consumption of each technology. It is very detailed and very informative.

Comment: @dim This article seems a bit speculative to me. How can one tell "An ANT device is configured to transmit 32 bytes/second and consumes 61 μA" without talking about a specific chip?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I don't know the ANT spec, but 32 bytes/sec is certainly some average throughput defined by it, and power consumption is estimated from a typical module, indeed, but this still allows technology comparisons if we consider all modules of a given technology to have similar performances (which seems a reasonable assumption to me).

Comment: @dim Does the spec prohibit to build a module in the future which consumes half of that amount? This article will get less and less useful with time, similar to shopping questions.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev if you look at the μJ/bit results, for example, you'll see that the results differs by several order of magnitude from technology to technology. So if, from module to module, you have half the consumption or twice the consumption, it is not really relevant. Well, I'm not really trying to convince anyone, anyway. I just give my point of view.

Comment: @dim That μJ/bit unit isn't derived from the protocol properties, it's still device-dependent. Look closer: they simply took the power of a **given chip** and divided by the bandwidth of **that same chip**. In the same spirit protocols could be compared by μJ/pin metric.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yes, I understand well they obtained the results using the method you describe. For a given chip. But I just keep thinking it gives a valid (although rough) idea of what would be the consumption for a given technology (whatever the module) for the reason I mentioned above. And yes, I can be a bit stubborn, sometimes.

Comment: There will be differences in the PHY energy efficiency of different tech, but not by orders of magnitude. What does make a difference of consumption by orders of magnitude is how you want to be able to interact with your sensor nodes. If they're asynchronous, with an Aloha-type MAC and a store-and-forward piggy-back downlink, power budget can be absolutely minuscule. OTOH, if you require your nodes to stay synchronized because you want to be able to ping them at any time, this can burn a lot of power. Please add such constraints.

Comment: @Sylvain I don't need to ping the nodes at any time. They will be syncronized through using an RTC in each node, and time slotted to transmit very rarely. I am not familiar with some of the terms you suggest - can you give any examples of commercial products using this scheme?

Comment: Why not use MQQT protocol?

Comment: I don't know. Why use it?